# Unity 5 上で ADV ツールアセット「宴」2.0 は動作しますか？

Tags: unity3d, 宴

現在 Unity 5 へのアップグレードを考えています。

Unity 5 上で「宴」は正しく動作しますでしょうか？

どなたか確認した方がいらっしゃいましたらご報告頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/jp/#!/publisher/6382 のサポートメールから開発者へ対応状況を問い合わせるのはダメなのでしょうか？ 公式ページを見ると Unity4.6 の対応情報が記載されていますので、現状、サポート対象外のように見えます。

Comment: @madapaja 「宴」の公式HPのサポートの一部がここ（ここで「ここ」とはここのこと）を推奨しているので大丈夫かもしれません。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 失礼しました。そこまで確認できていませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Unity 5 対応後に回答がミスリーディングな状態にならないように、現時点のバージョン情報をタイトルに入れました。意図しているバージョンと違っていた場合は、お手数ですが[edit]をおねがいします。

Answer (score 5):

「宴」開発者の時村です。

Unity5でも動作するようにしていこうと思っています。
基本的にはUnity5でも今までのアセットは動作するはずなので、特に問題ないと思い
ます。以前、Unity5の先行βテスト版を使った際には問題なく動作しました。

もし、Unity5で不具合があるようでしたら公式サイトのQ＆Aのほうにご連絡ください。
http://madnesslabo.net/utage/?page_id=1011
（StackOverFlowのガイドラインでは、製品のQ&Aに使うのは問題ないのですが、バグ報告などは製品の公式サイトなどに誘導することとあるので。お手数おかけしますがよろしくお願いします）

また、Unity5からWebGL向けのビルドができるのですが、これについてはサポートできるかわかりません。
現在Unity5のWebGLはまだ不具合が多いらしく、また正式リリースの仕様でも機能制限があるようなので、その辺の情報がUnity社から正式に発表されるまでは判断がつかない状況です。

Answer (score 3):

「宴」開発者の時村です。

Unity5対応済みの宴（version2.10）を公開しました。
また、Unity5で発生する自動コンバートの差分やワーニングも全て対応しました。
Unity4とUnity5で同じように動作するはずです。

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/jp/#!/content/15905